# weird grails error message

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

Using grails 1.1.1 
I got this message when I did a modification on a service and then tried to refresh the page.

I have a controller name ContributionPlanController.
It has a service ContributionPlanservice.

inside the ContributionPlanService, it has ProductService and some other Services including JointPIAService.

JointPIAService it self, inherited from ProductService

I did a modification on ProductService, like println on something and this errors always appeared. If I restarted the application, it will works fine.

Any idea how to solve this ?

=========================================================================================

> ```
> Message: Could not initialize class
> ```
>
> JointPIAService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e27c7697
>   Caused by: Error creating bean with
>   name 'ContributionPlanController':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'contributionPlanService': Cannot
>   create inner bean '(inner bean)' while
>   setting bean property 'target'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner
>   bean)#21': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'jointPIAService': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException:
>   Could not generate CGLIB subclass of
>   class [class JointPIAService]: Common
>   causes of this problem include using a
>   final class or a non-visible class;
>   nested exception is
>   net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
>   Class: Unknown At Line: [-1] Code
>   Snippet:

Stack Trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ContributionPlanController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contributionPlanService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#21': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jointPIAService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class JointPIAService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(JSecurityFilter.java:382)

    at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:180)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contributionPlanService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#21': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jointPIAService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class JointPIAService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    ... 3 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#21': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jointPIAService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class JointPIAService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    ... 4 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jointPIAService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class JointPIAService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    ... 5 more

Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class JointPIAService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    ... 6 more

Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:622)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:609)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createUsingReflection(Enhancer.java:631)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.firstInstance(Enhancer.java:538)

    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)

    ... 6 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:616)

    ... 12 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class JointPIAService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e27c7697

    ... 13 more
```

==========================================================================================

Answer (score 2):

When you declared ContributionPlanService within ContributionPlanController, did you do so with explicit typing ("ContributionPlanService contributionPlanService") or with dynamic typing ("def contributionPlanService")?

In 1.0.4, the combination of auto-wiring and hot swapping only worked with dynamic typing (def ...).  That is, that an explicitly declared service would get auto-wired okay the first time you start up the app, but that the hot swapping is foiled thereafter.  Changing the declaring to def would make the hot swapping work, but then you lose the benefit of your IDE helping you out.

Now that you mention it, I was hoping this would be fixed in 1.1.x, but I haven't tried it yet.  (I'm not in a position to test it right this moment, but I didn't want to wait to send you this answer.  Try it and let me know.)

Comment: i am using dynamic typing def contributionPlanService;

I thought it happened because JointPIAService inherited from ProductService

Comment: Oh, I see.  You modified the base class of a service.  Yeah, I'm not surprised that the auto-wiring can't keep up with that.  You might want to rethink the way you are using abstraction here.  Where you currently have service B is a descendant of service A, change it so that B is a separate service on its own that merely uses A -- unless of course there's a solid design reason why you really need polymorphism here.